# How is Intel's Remote Management Module (RMM4) different from Supermicro's IPMI/BMC?

Tags: intel, ipmi, supermicro, bmc

I am new to IPMI BMC (always used KVM) and I would like to understand what are the differences between Intel's implementation on IPMI BMC using its RMM4 module and that of Supermicro?

I've read though the [documentation](http://download.intel.com/support/motherboards/server/sb/intel_rmm4_ibwc_userguide_r2_72.pdf) and appears pretty standard. Are there any additional security features? I noticed that Supermicro have a mobile app, is there anything similar for Intel?

Are there any other differences (aside from needing to purchase Intel's module separately), benefits or drawbacks between Intel and Supermicro?